# Angular table with selectable columns or rows

Tags: angular, calendar, components

I'm building a screen which requires a calendar component in an Angular (v11) app. My calendar looks similar to this (below) - it's a week view, broken up by hour blocks:

[image]

When the user mouse-downs and drags over rows it should highlight in blue multiple rows columns until mouse-up where it becomes green (accepted).

My question - I could possibly build a table component that works in this fashion from scratch but before starting, I was wondering - has any one built something like this or used one from a component library on NPM etc.

Any pointers in advance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of an obscure question - but thought I'd put down what I found was useful for my use-case.

I decided to use the PrimeNG controls to achieve what I needed.  No idea if its useful for others but you can find the specific component here:  https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/calendar